# How can I get value of HTML tags and use them in Angular 2 component?

Tags: angular, data-binding

I'm new at Angular 2 and not so familiar with the syntax of it. I have a form that in html page there are inputs and selections and like these.

Most of them don't have any component just value in HTML tags. But I want to get these values from HTML and use them in my component. I searched a lot but wasn't successful. How can I write whatever it needs in both HTML and ts pages?

For example this is a part of my form:

```
<select class="form-control " id="sel1">
                        <option disabled>type</option>
                        <option>apartment</option>
                        <option>store</option>
                        <option>villa</option>
                        <option>ofiice</option>
                    </select>
```

I should notice that when I wanted to ask this question I had searched before bur I didn't get my answer.

Comment: So you searched "Angular form" and didn't get anything? Because there is *loads* of information out there, from the official docs and elsewhere. For example: https://angular.io/guide/forms

Comment: It should be the other way around, you should have these values in your Angular component(s) and then use them in HTML.

Comment: @tima Are you sure there is no other way?

Comment: @AmirGh The other way is somehow loading the HTML into a string or file and then parsing it in Angular to get the values. It can be done, it's not a good way to do this though.

Comment: @tima I think so. It won't be a good way. But if I want to make a separate component for each one how should I write the code in html and ts? Because I'm not professional in angular 2. Thank you

Comment: @AmirGh you should start with the official tutorial https://angular.io/tutorial. It is pretty good and covers a bunch of concepts, not just Hello World.

Comment: @tima ok thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much search I found the answer:
for select and option tag in html page:

```
<select #selecttypes>
                    <option disabled>type</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="type.id">{{type.name}}</option>
</select>
<button (click)=onSubmit($event,selecttypes)>Submit</button>
```

for example you want to put these values in a class of ***Building*** with ***typeofbuilding*** property.
and in component.ts:

```
import {Building} from './building';
export class Component {
constructor(private building: Building) {}
types: any[] = [
{id:1,name:'Apartment'},
{id:2,name:'Store'},
{id:3,name:'Villa'},
{id:4,name:'Office'},
];
onSubmit($event: any,selecttypes: string){
$event.preventDefault();
this.building.typeofbuilding= selecttypes;
console.log(this.building.typeofbuilding)
 }
}
```

for input tag:
in html page:

```
<input #rooms name="username" type="text" required>
<button (click)="onSubmit($event,rooms.value)>Submit</button>
```

in ***Building*** class there is another property ***numofrooms***. So the
component.ts is :

```
import {Building} from './building';
export class Component {
constructor(private building: Building) {}
onSubmit($event: any,rooms: number){
$event.preventDefault();
this.building.numofrooms= rooms;
console.log(this.building.numofrooms)
 }
}
```

I hope it will be useful.